# How to compare time in java

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have the following format for time "hh:mm:ss" .
Now I have two time values such as,

```
Date previous_time=20:50:55
Date current_time=19:50:55
```

And I am trying to compare it like this,

```
if(previous_time.after(current_date)){
  Log.i("Time Comparision","before is true");
      System.out.println("before");  
}
else if(current_time.after(previous_time)){
  Log.i("Time Comparision","after is true");
  System.out.println("after");   
}
else {
  System.out.println("nothing");
  Log.i("Time Comparision not happened","");
}
```

But both my if conditions are not working.
 My question is, how to compare two times when they are in the above mentioned format?

Comment: Are you just giving examples of what the times are or are you saying that is how you are constructing the dates?

Comment: Yes, this is how I have my time values. I have to compare it.

Comment: The `else` clause means the times are equal, not that the comparison failed.  The comparison looks OK, so you need to check how you are constructing the time values.

Comment: yes I accept with your point. Can you help me to reconstruct my if condition, so that if my previous time is before my current time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line of code you refer to current_date not current_time.

Either that's the problem or the two dates are equal, which would execute the part in else.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to compare it via Date.getTime() function, which returns milliseconds after 1/1/1970.